# Динамическое добавление полей формы yii2

Tags: php, yii2, activeform

Каким образом при помощи active form yii2 можно реализовать динамическое добавление блока полей формы на фронте? Т.е. есть форма из 5 полей и блока из 5 полей всего 10 полей и  кнопка добавить блок , по нажатию на нее добавиться еще один валидируемый блок из 5 полей.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я когда-то решал подобную задачу, но у меня не было клиентской валидации. Возможно она будет работать при клонировании.

```
var parent = $(this).parents('.answers');
var block = parent.find('.answer').last();
var cln = block.clone();
parent.append(cln);
```

При клонировании необходимо предусмотреть очистку полей, если там будут данные.

Вполне возможет вариант создания экшена, который будет возвращать необходимые поля. По клику аяксом запрашивать этот экшн и вставлять в форму. В таком случае не надо будет очищать поля от данных, но возникнет небольшая задержка по времени.

Comment: в принципе так и сделал  , после клона пришлось js очистить поля прогнать через yii валидацию , и выставить атрибуты для полей в виде name = nameForm[0][nameField], чтобы потом их получить в массиве на беке .