# YII2 динамическая форма

Tags: php, jquery, yii2, activeform

YII2. Каким образом можно создать динамическую форму и потом добавить все данные в базу данных? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы хотите сначала создать на клиенте таблицу, а после нажатия кнопки save добавить введенные данные? я верно понял?

Comment: Да, все данные, которые мы заполнили в динамической форме попадают в таблицу.

Comment: 1) Вам нужна кнопка, для добавления новой записи на клиенте (Добавить счет), по ее нажатию будут появляться поля, для введения еще одного счета. Либо это можно сделать так: Пользователь начинает вводить данные, и сразу появляются еще поля для ввода следующего счета, и так по циклу. 2) По нажатию save посылаете запрос на эту же страницу (post или get сами решите) 3) В yii проверяейте на экшене этой страници `if(Yii::$app->request->post("имя_фармы"))` то создаем новый счет (экземляр модели его) 4) Модель сформируйте через `gii`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимые поля выводить в блоке, с помощью js клонировать блок, очистить данные, сделать валидацию, добавить/исправить необходимые атрибуты.

На сервере используем принцип табличного ввода. https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/input-tabular-input.md

Похожий вопрос
[Динамическое добавление полей формы yii2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/829922/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B-yii2/831534#comment1330044_831534)