# Динамическое добавление input в ActiveForm Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать динамическое добавление полей в форму ActiveForm. Сейчас у меня есть следующая форма:
[image: Форма добавления нового якоря]

Сейчас реализован только функционал вывода якорей статей из базы данных.
Предполагается , что при нажатии кнопки "Добавить якорь" - в форму добавиться новая группа input - 2шт.и их можно будет успешно сохранить в базу данных. 
Контроллер :

```
    /**
 * Updates an existing Article model.
 * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
 * @param integer $id
 * @return mixed
 * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
 */
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    $modelArticleAnchors = $this->findArticleAnchorsModel($model->id);
    $error = false;
    $errors=[];

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post() )) {
        $meta=new MetaComponent(new RelateTableFactory());
        $meta->build($id,Yii::$app->request->post(),$model->formName(),'meta_items');
    }

    Model::loadMultiple($modelArticleAnchors,Yii::$app->request->post());
    foreach($modelArticleAnchors as $articleAnchors){
            $articleAnchors->save();            
    }

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['update', 'id' => $model->id]);
    }

    if($model->hasErrors()){
        $error = true;
        $errors = $model->getErrors();
    }

    return $this->render('update', [
        'model' => $model,
        'modelArticleAnchors' => $modelArticleAnchors,
        'error'=>$error,
        'errors'=>$errors
    ]);
}
```

View:

```
        <div id="anchor_container">

        <?php foreach($modelArticleAnchors as $index => $articleAnchor): ?>
        <div class="col-lg-12 anchor-container_inner">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <?= $form->field($articleAnchor, "[$index]anchor_text")->textInput(); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <?= $form->field($articleAnchor, "[$index]anchor_id")->textInput(); ?>        
            </div>    
        </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

   </div>
    <button type="button" id="insertRowButton" class="btn btn-primary">Добавить якорь</button>
```

Comment: https://toster.ru/q/10517

Comment: Вот тут отвечал на аналогичный вопрос. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/829922/Динамическое-добавление-полей-формы-yii2/831534#831534